# jQuery slide up from bottom, can't get upper content to not overlap

Tags: jquery, css

When I click the `toggle` button, I want `#upper` to slide *up* from the bottom. However, I can't get `#lower` to stay at the bottom and not have the content from `#upper` overlap it. How can I fix this?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4k6du/136/

Page in question: http://keebs.com/sandbox

HTML

```
<div id="upper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat. Nam iaculis dolor et est tristique scelerisque. Integer gravida scelerisque est, ut pellentesque sem facilisis in. Quisque felis elit, laoreet id sagittis non, sollicitudin vitae turpis. Pellentesque quis quam sed nibh sollicitudin porttitor non ac sapien. Cras luctus egestas urna, vitae bibendum enim malesuada ut. Nulla porta tempus mi vel consequat. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros.</p>
</div>

<div id="lower">
    <div id="toggle-div">
    <a href="#" id="toggle">button</a>
    </div>

    <div id="panel">
        <p>Panel - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat. Nam iaculis dolor et est tristique scelerisque. Integer gravida scelerisque est, ut pellentesque sem facilisis in. Quisque felis elit, laoreet id sagittis non, sollicitudin vitae turpis. Pellentesque quis quam sed nibh sollicitudin porttitor non ac sapien. Cras luctus egestas urna, vitae bibendum enim malesuada ut. Nulla porta tempus mi vel consequat. Aenean scelerisque porttitor felis, id elementum erat porttitor eu. Mauris vitae elit non lorem malesuada viverra non ac eros.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="copyright">
        copyright info
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#upper {
    position: relative;
}

#lower {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#toggle-div {
    padding: 10px;
    background:#666;
}

#panel {
    display: none;
/*    height: 100px;*/
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    padding: 10px;
}
#copyright {
    width:100%;
    background:#222;
    height:40px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    if ($('#panel').css('display') == 'block') {
        var height = '-=' + $('#panel').height();
    } else {
        var height = '+=' + $('#panel').height();
    }
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#upper").animate({
        bottom: height
    }, "slow")
});
```

Comment: So you want both `#lower` and `#upper` to be positioned at the bottom? And then you want `#lower` to stay as-is and you want `#upper` to slide up so that it's entirely above `#lower`? Why are you animating `#panel` if you want that to stay in place?

Comment: @matthewpavkov I just want `#lower` to always remain at the bottom of the page. When the button is clicked, I want the hidden panel to "push" everything above it up instead of having the panel slide down. I added the page in question to the original post. If you scroll to the bottom and click the 'contact' link, you'll notice that the panel slides down. I just want it to push the page up so if the user happens to not be all the way at the bottom and click the link, he'll still notice the panel when it shows. Sorry I'm horrible at explaining things.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem.

Comment: @matthewpavkov I wrapped the above and lower content in `#upper` and `#lower` but I don't even know if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main objective here is to let the user know that new content has been shown. While it's possible to achieve this in the way you want, I would suggest trying something simpler, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDBbE/2/

```
$('#toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $('.slide-container');
    if($el.is(':visible'))
    {
        $el.slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $el.slideDown(300);
        scrollToContent($el);
    }
});

function scrollToContent($el) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $el.offset().top }, 600);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that when the toggle button is clicked, it flickers for a second and `#footer` moves down and up. Can this be changed so that it doesn't flicker and `#footer` remains still?

Comment: The updated code doesn't flicker. What's happening is, as `slide-container` is sliding down, the browser is scrolling down to the bottom. You can adjust the timing values (`300`, `300`, and `600`) to make the animation appear/feel different.